# IIS 6 localhost works but nothing else does

Tags: iis-6, localhost

If I type localost in IE, it yields "It works!" but I can't seem to locate where exactly that page is picked from.

In c:\InetPub\wwwroot\ nothing exists that points "It works!" page.

---

I created a test folder inside wwwroot above. I put an aspx file there, it does not work (no file found), then i created a test.htm file, that can not be accessed through localhost/test/test.htm

Anyone knows what is wrong. I never ran IIS on this particular system. I have Windows XP Pro, and IIS6 is installed.

Please help.

Comment: Did you checked, if the website is really pointing to this particular folder?

Comment: Check if the folder in inetmgr is pointing to which location.It may be located somewhere else in the machine.also check if you have set application pool for that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will answer it myself. There were two confusion first of all, IIS 5.1 was installed along with IIS 6 (there was a link in Administrative tools) and Apache server as well. Something was probably messing with it before I came. I uninstalled Apache, IIS 6 link (was not supposed to be there in the first place), and even IIS. Fresh installed fixed everything.

Also if you are running into problem like this, get familiar with IIS, how it works. It runs out of Virtual folders and you have to turn these virtual folders into Applications. It is tricky the way Microsoft do it.

In my case probably both the server were using the default port 80 (I am not sure though). I now have both servers intalled (IIS + Apache), with Apache using port 8080.

To test situation like this, do this: create a virtual folder in IIS 5.1, right click on it and turn that folder into application. Put an aspx file in the "actual" location that this virtual folder points to see and then open it in browser using localhost\virtualfolder\myaspx.file. Note that in many case IIS will not pick the default.aspx file automaticaly unless explicity given.